# Interacting with a large java program as a service?

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, sockets, apache-nifi

How can I do the following?

What I want to do is load Stanford NLP ONCE, then interact with it via an HTTP or other endpoint. The reason is that it takes a long time to load, and loading for every string to analyze is out of the question.

For example, here is Stanford NLP loading in a simple C# program that loads the jars... I'm looking to do what I did below, but in java:

```
    Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [9.3 sec]. 
    Loading classifier from D:\Repositories\StanfordNLPCoreNLP\stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models\edu\stanford\nlp\models\ner\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [12.8 sec]. 
    Loading classifier from D:\Repositories\StanfordNLPCoreNLP\stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models\edu\stanford\nlp\models\ner\english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [5.9 sec]. 
    Loading classifier from D:\Repositories\StanfordNLPCoreNLP\stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models\edu\stanford\nlp\models\ner\english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ...  done [4.1 sec]. 
done [8.8 sec]. 

Sentence #1 ...
```

This is over 30 seconds. If these all have to load each time, yikes. To show what I want to do in java, I wrote a working example in C#, and this complete example may help someone some day:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.IO;
using java.io;
using java.util;
using edu.stanford.nlp;
using edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline;
using Console = System.Console;

namespace NLPConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Path to the folder with models extracted from `stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models.jar`
            var jarRoot = @"..\..\..\..\StanfordNLPCoreNLP\stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models";
            // Text for intial run processing
            var text = "Kosgi Santosh sent an email to Stanford University. He didn't get a reply.";
            // Annotation pipeline configuration
            var props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, sentiment"); 
            props.setProperty("ner.useSUTime", "0");
            // We should change current directory, so StanfordCoreNLP could find all the model files automatically
            var curDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(jarRoot);
            var pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(curDir);
            // loop
            while (text != "quit")
            {
                // Annotation
                var annotation = new Annotation(text);
                pipeline.annotate(annotation);
                // Result - Pretty Print
                using (var stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
                {
                    pipeline.prettyPrint(annotation, new PrintWriter(stream));
                    Console.WriteLine(stream.toString());
                    stream.close();
                }
                edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreePrint tprint = new edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreePrint("words");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a sentence to evaluate, and hit ENTER (enter \"quit\" to quit)");
                text = Console.ReadLine();
            } // end while
        }
    }
}
```

So it takes the 30 seconds to load, but each time you give it a string on the console, it takes the smallest fraction of a second to parse & tokenize that string.

You can see that I loaded the jar files prior to the while loop.

This may end up being a socket service, HTML, or something else that will entertain requests (in the form of strings), and spit back the parsing.

My ultimate goal is to use a mechanism in Nifi, via a processor that can send strings to be parsed, and have them returned in less than a second, versus 30+ seconds if a traditional web server threaded example (for instance) is used. Every request would load the whole thing for 30 seconds, THEN get down to business. I hope I made this clear!

How to do this?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for direction in how to use Apache NiFi to utilize Standford's NLP (which could then be added as a step in a Wbe Service Flow)? Is there a reason you're involving C# and don't just write a NiFi processor using the java NLP libraries? You could initialize everything in the OnSchedule method and then process the Strings as they come in in the OnTrigger

Comment: OK. Let me rephrase: "What I want to do is load Stanford NLP ONCE, then interact with it via an HTTP or other endpoint." to say "How can I load Stanford NLP ONCE, then interact with it via an HTTP or other endpoint.". But the question might be the same for any Java process that takes time to load, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the mechanisms you list are perfectly reasonable routes forward for leveraging that service with Apache NiFi.  Depending on your needs, some of the processors and extensions that are bundled with the standard release of NiFi may be sufficient to interact with your proposed web service or similar offering.

If you are striving for performing all of this within NiFi itself, a custom [Controller Service](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#controller-services) might be a great path to provide this resource to NiFi that falls within the lifecycle of the application itself.

NiFi can be extended with items like controller services and custom processors and we have some [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html) to get you started down that path.

Additional details could certainly help to provide some more information.  Feel free to follow up on here with additional comments and/or reach out to the community via our [mailing lists](http://nifi.apache.org/mailing_lists.html).

One item I did want to call out if it was unclear that NiFi is JVM driven and work would be done in Java or JVM friendly languages.

Comment: this is really good. I want to have text parser/taggers as services that Nifi can send text to, and out comes the tagging. Without knowing about Nifi services, I was thinking creating some kind of service that would multi-tread, yet not load the code (30sec+) for each thread. It may be easier to create the Nifi service than a web/port service... I have a lot of work ahead, but this gives me some tangible direction instead of guessing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [the new CoreNLP Server](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html) which Stanford NLP introduced in version 3.6.0. It seems like it does just what you want?  Some other people such as [ETS](https://github.com/EducationalTestingService/stanford-thrift) have done similar things.

Fine point: If using this heavily, you might (at present) want to grab the latest CoreNLP code from [github HEAD](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP), since it contains a few fixes to the server which will be in the next release.

Comment: Christopher, I can't vote your answer up... I glanced over the server, but should have read further. I thought my main problem was how to run a java program that would take inputs & give outputs without reloading. But it would be single threaded (bad). I'll look into the NLP server! Thanks!